# Detection of framework usage on Mac system?

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks, dynamic-library

I wanted to develop sample framework on OSX with having requirement that at any point in time the framework should be used by only single client, i am not getting how to achieve this ? is their any API's to detect weather the framework is in use? can we use some file related API for this?..i have seen a windows sample where they where detecting the dylib's usage using 
Following API's ??
CreateFileMappingW
MapViewOfFile
OpenFileMappingW

Does anyone has come across such scenarios??

Comment: You'll need to maintain a system-wide resource which can be used to hold references to the apps that are currently using your framework.  This is complicated as you will have to deal with app crashes where this *store* is not cleaned-up properly and it will be almost impossible to defeat the app sandboxing that currently the standard.  I would say this is very hard to achieve without infuriating your users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lsof](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html) command. it will return list of open files.

> In the absence of any options, lsof lists all open files belonging to
>   all active processes.

```
NSTask* task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
NSPipe* pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];

NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"lsof | grep -i some.framework | wc -l",nil];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments: args];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task setStandardError: pipe];
[task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]]; 
[task launch];    
[task waitUntilExit];

NSFileHandle* file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [file readDataToEndOfFile] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
[result release];
[task release];
[pipe release];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great in command line but how do i execute following command in cocoa
lsof | grep -i some.framework | wc -l

i used NSTask and passed "| grep -i some.framework | wc -l "these as arguments nut gives error, do you know how to achieve this??